# Gnuplot - best choice to plot very wide graph

Tags: gnuplot

I have a very large set of data, they are hourly measurements and I have to plot 6 years of recordings, so we have about 8760 * 6 ~ 50'000 data.
x-axes is in date-time format.

Up to now I plotted a single year data, so about 10'000 data.
In a single "screen" I want to see about 30-50 hours width, so I have setted a width of 60'000:

`set terminal png size 60000,2000`

In that way, gnuplot creates a ridiculously wide PNG image. Anyway it is possible to visualize it with a browser, zoom it to 100% and scroll left and right to easily analyze my data.

Now, if I have to monitor 6 years instead of 1, I need an output image 6 times greater. So I tried:

`set terminal png size 360000,2000`

output image is now very wide and my browser cannot open it. I think due to the big size. However I can open it with an image viewer like "gwenview".
Anyway browser would be better, because I have to send this graph to other people.

Which alternative output "terminal" could I use in gnuplot to obtain a more manageable image?

---

EDIT:

I tried SVG terminal. It seems better to produce images of this size:

`set terminal svg size 360000,800
set output 'plot.svg'`

The image plot.svg is about 11 MB, very big, but browser can open it without any problem.
I have to visualize this large amount of data just for a "quality quick check" and scroll from the left to the right within the browser is easy enough. If I has to open many split image files it would be more complicated and slow.

Any other idea is welcome, thanks!

Comment: I tried pdfcairo, and a size of 180,1 inches worked, 360,2 produced only a blank page in my Adobe viewer.

Comment: @Karl According to the pdf-spec, the maximum allowed page size is 14000x14000 units, the default user space unit is 1/72 inch, so you have a maximum pdf-size of 200in x 200in.

Comment: To be frank, what you are trying to do seems pretty insane. Do you really think the other people will appreciate going through thousands of screens of plot (and that’s literal: 50000 h / 50 h = 1000)? Nobody (including you) should view this amount of data manually. For the sake of your audience: Either give them the raw data or apply some reasonable reduction to your data (e.g., a moving average or picking the relevant parts) and then pass on the results.

Comment: why don't you use multiplot and stack 6 plots (one for each year one) below the other?